migrate materialized vues to mongo atlas
Given i have a postgreSQL database with foreign tables linked to  mongo collections.
And some materialized views exposing data from these foreign tables
I need to remove completely postgreSQL
The mapping between foreign tables and collections is very straightforward so no problem.
My concern is on the  materialized views, because lot of complexity.
Is there way in mongo atlas to create kind of sql like vues in order to "copy paste" these views into mongo altlas ?
Or i will have to convert them into mongo aggregation framework ?
Thanks

Like this? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/materialized-views/#std-label-manual-materialized-views
